# Error (10327): can't determine definition of operator ""="" -- found 0 possible definitions

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL '93 the compiler told me it found 0 possible definitions for operator "=".
It causes an error with the following error message:

```
Error (10327): VHDL error at mst_fifo_fsm.vhd(171): can't determine definition of operator ""="" -- found 0 possible definitions
```

Line 171 is at the first assignment of ifsm_cond(0):

```
process(clk, rst_n) 
begin
if (rst_n = '0') then
    ifsm_cond <= "0000";
elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
    if (mltcn = '0') then
        ifsm_cond(0) <= (cur_stap1 = IDLE) AND (not imst_rd_n(0)) AND (not rxf_n) AND (not ibuf_ful(0));
        ifsm_cond(1) <= (cur_state = MTRD) AND ( imst_rd_n(0)  OR (rxf_n  AND (not rxf_n_p1))  OR ibuf_ful(0)) ;
        ifsm_cond(2) <= (cur_state = MDLE) AND (not imst_wr_n(0)) AND (not txe_n)& (ibuf_nep(0)  OR stren OR w_1byte) AND (not w_1flag);
        ifsm_cond(3) <= (cur_stap3 = MTWR) AND ( imst_wr_n(0)  OR (txe_n  AND (not txe_n_p1))  OR r_oobe OR ((not ififonempt(0)) AND (not stren) AND (not prefnempt(0))));
    else
        ifsm_cond(0) <= (not imst_rd_n(conv_integer(ichannel))) AND (not irxf_n(conv_integer(ichannel))) AND (not ibuf_ful(conv_integer(ichannel))) AND (cur_stap3 = IDLE);
        ifsm_cond(1) <= ( imst_rd_n(conv_integer(ichannel))  OR (rxf_n & (not rxf_n_p1)) OR ibuf_ful(conv_integer(ichannel))) AND (cur_state = MTRD);
        ifsm_cond(2) <= (not imst_wr_n(conv_integer(ichannel))) AND (not itxe_n(conv_integer(ichannel)))  AND (ibuf_nep(conv_integer(ichannel)) OR stren) AND (cur_stap3 = MDLE);
        ifsm_cond(2) <= (not imst_wr_n(conv_integer(ichannel))) AND (not itxe_n(conv_integer(ichannel)))  AND (ibuf_nep(conv_integer(ichannel)) OR stren) AND (cur_stap3 = MDLE);
        ifsm_cond(3) <= ( imst_wr_n(conv_integer(ichannel))  OR (rxf_n AND 
        (not rxf_n_p1)) OR ((not ififonempt(conv_integer(ichannel)) AND (not stren) 
        AND (not prefnempt(conv_integer(ichannel)))))) AND (cur_stap3 = MTWR);
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

I guess it is at the statement (cur_stap1 = IDLE).

cur_stap1 is a user defined signal with the following declaration:

```
type states is (IDLE, MTRD, MDLE, MTWR);
signal cur_state, next_statem, cur_stap1, cur_stap2, cur_stap3, cur_stap4 : 
states;
```

I thougt of one possible solution to clarify first in a conditional concurrent signal assignment if cur_stap1 is IDLE and assign this to a signal which replaces (cur_stap1 = IDLE). But I have some more lines with other statements like this.

Is there a better solution to solve this issue? This concurrent signal assignment is done in a process. Should I rather try an IF ELSIF END IF statement for the whole line?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including context clause/items and declarations. A complete error message can also be helpful. Otherwise without knowing better cur_stap = IDLE would appear to return a boolean value. The likes of `not rxf_n`, a value of the type rxf_n is declared to be. There'd be no predefined logical operators mixing booleans and different types as operands. Consider learning operator precedence, none of the expression parentheses are needed.

Comment: Yes you can use that operator there. But you have to make sure exactly one matching `=` function declaration is visible. Make this an [MCVE] and we'll be able to see the error. But either NO `=` is visible (you're comparing different types or returning the wrong type ... boolean where you need std_logic) or two or more are (perhaps you wrote your own `=` and there's an intrinsic one too).

Comment: @BrianDrummond I edited above post. I think I need std_logic but (cur_stap1 = IDLE) will give me a boolean return type. What do you mean with matching = function declaration?

Comment: @JHBonarius I changed it to the desired information.

Comment: Now we have the declarations we can see there are no `=` functions matching the argument and return types, specifically, no `function "=" (L,R : states) return std_logic;` whereas this code requires one. Not necessarily recommending this approach (except as an exercise in understanding VHDL), but : there's nothing to stop you writing one.

Comment: How was `ifsm_cond` declared? it is a boolean, bit ord std_logic vector? You are mixing different types for truth logic.

Comment: IMHO this error is caused by bad design. You have a state machine with six signals representing a state. That's asking for design difficulties. It gives very strange dependencies for these state machine output signals. I would suggest a redesign.

Comment: **Some questions are still [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:** 1. Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* __must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error VHDL Quartus: can't determine definition of operator ""="" -- found 0 possible definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497800/error-vhdl-quartus-cant-determine-definition-of-operator-found-0-poss)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `not imst_rd_n(0)` returns a `std_logic` type, while `cur_stap1 = IDLE` returns a `boolean` type. There is no `and` operator that accepts both types, thus the compiler tries to solve it another way: by looking for an `=` operator defined for your custom type (state) that returns a `std_logic`, which there isn't. Hence the error.

Instead of `not imst_rd_n(0)`, you should write `imst_rd_n(0)='0'` and so on. This returns a `boolean` and a `boolean` `and` operator is defined. Imho it's also better for readability.
You should then write your assignment in an `if` statement.

```
If [boolean expression] then
    [Signal] <= '1';
Else
    [Signal] <= '0';
End if;
```

Also try to design a state machine with a simple output:

```
Case [current_state] is
    When [state 1] =>
        If ....
    When ....
End case;
```

You can work with default assignment.
Example:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
    ifsm_cond <= (others => '0'); -- default assignment
    case cur_state is
        when IDLE =>
            if imst_rd_n(0)='0' AND rxf_n='0' AND ibuf_ful='0' then
                ifsm_cond(0) <= '1';
            end if;
        when MTRD =>
            if imst_rd_n(0)='1'  OR (rxf_n='1'  AND rxf_n_p1='0')  OR ibuf_ful(0)='1' then
                ifsm_cond(1) <= '1';
            end if;
```

etc.

---

I would not write a function for operator `=` for two input's type `states` that returns a `std_logic`, as that could lead to other unwanted conflicts. I would instead propose to make a casting function from `boolean` to `std_logic`. E.g.:

```
function to_std_logic(input : boolean) return std_ulogic is
begin
    if input then
        return '1';
    end if;
    return '0';
end function;
```

Usage example: `ifsm_cond(0) <= to_std_logic(cur_stap1 = IDLE) AND (not imst_rd_n(0)) AND (not rxf_n) AND (not ibuf_ful(0));`